# How to check if the String object passed to the method contains at least one of the words from the list- JAVA

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I need help with creating a method that takes an object of the String type in the input arguments and a list of objects of the String type. The list contains forbidden words. How can I check if the String object passed to the method contains at least one of the words from the list?

```
public class Filter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        wordsFilter("This sentence contains a forbidden word");
    }
    
    private static void wordsFilter(String sentence) {
        List<String> forbiddenWords = new ArrayList<>();
        forbiddenWords.add("forbiddenWord");
        forbiddenWords.add("forbidden word");

        for (String word : forbiddenWords) {
            if (sentence.contains(word)) {
                System.out.println("The content cannot be displayed");
            } else {
                System.out.println(sentence);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a condition to exit the loop when a forbidden word was found:

```
private static void wordsFilter(String sentence) {
        List<String> forbiddenWords = new ArrayList<>();
        forbiddenWords.add("forbiddenWord");
        forbiddenWords.add("forbidden word");

        boolean doesContainAnyForbiddenWords = false;

        for (String word : forbiddenWords) {
            if (sentence.contains(word)) {
                doesContainAnyForbiddenWords = true;
                break; // leave the loop
            } else {
                System.out.println(sentence);
            }
        }

        if (doesContainAnyForbiddenWords) {
            System.out.println("The content cannot be displayed");
        } else {
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The output is: 
This sentence contains a forbidden word
The content cannot be displayed
What should be displayed is only "The content cannot be displayed". If I remove else statment  is it correct with "coding rules"?:)

for (String word : forbiddenWords) {
            if (sentence.contains(word)) {
                doesContainAnyForbiddenWords = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (doesContainAnyForbiddenWords) {
            System.out.println("The content cannot be displayed");
        } else {
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using the [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API

```
Optional<String> potential_forbidden_word = 
    forbiddenWords.stream().filter(word -> sentence.contains(word)).findFirst();
if(potential_forbidden_word.isPresent())
    System.out.println("don't usw: "+potential_forbidden_word.get());
else
    System.out.println("the sentence is clean");
```

you can even shorten the stream:

```
Optional<String> potential_forbidden_word = 
    forbiddenWords.stream().filter(sentence::contains).findFirst();
```

AS @Adriaan Koster mentioned: you can simply use the terminal operation anyMatch(Predicate):

```
boolean contains_forbidden_word = 
    forbiddenWords.stream().anyMatch(sentence::contains);
```

you might check for with equalsIgnoreCase() because "foo" or "Foo" or "FoO" and so on might also be forbidden.

Comment: You don't even have to use filter & findFirst, instead you can use anyMatch(word -> sentence.contains(word));

Comment: @AdriaanKoster good point, I edited the answer, thanks.